# Generate slug when using ancestry gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ancestry

I'd like to create a slug based on the ancestors of the record. If I already have a slug created. The best solution I have come up with is:

```
def pretty_url    
  path.select(:slug).map(&:slug).join("-")
end
```

Is there a more precise way to do this using the ancestry gem?

Also, I am using friendly id to generate the slug, so maybe there is a better way using friendly id?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what I figured out, using friendly id and ancestry gem together.

```
friendly_id :slug_candidates, use: :slugged

 def slug_candidates
   [
     [parent.try(:slug), :title]
   ]
 end
```